# Logical taborder when element changes position

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I've got a problem with the taborder (keyboard focus) in a header. The header consists of a navigation, logo, some buttons and a link. In desktop the logo is left aligned and the menu is expanded but when the screen gets small the logo changes position to the center of the header and the menu is toggable with a hamburger icon. My issue is that if I put the navigation before the logo in the html, it works on small screens but in desktop the navigation gets focused first, which causes the user to navigate trough the whole navigation before going to the rest of the header content. So my question is, how can I solve it so that the taborder always start at the same position dispite which content it has? I don't want to set taborder=1, 2 etc.

Desktop:
[Logo] [Buttons] [Link]

[Expanded navigation] (below header)

Mobile: [Hamburger icon] [Logo] [Link]

I want the taborder to be Logo -> Buttons -> Link -> Expanded navigation, for desktop and for mobile: Hamburger -> Logo -> Link

I hope the question is understandable.

**EDIT**
Added an example of my problem: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a5ef0x8z/)

And this is the css in the example:

```
header {
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .button {
    display: none;
  }

  .content {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }

}
```

Comment: It might be better to add a working demo to get help faster.

Comment: I've updated my question with an example

Answer (score 0):

A common idiom is to provide a "skip links" tab stop at the very top of the document, or at least before the links you want to skip. This special tab stop can be hidden from view until focused with the tab key, so nobody needs to know it's there unless they're using a keyboard.

https://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/

Bear in mind that screen reader users will usually have alternative ways to navigate around the document without using explicit tab stops. Browsing by headings is very common, for example.

Comment: I don't see how that would ne helpful in my case, as I don't want to skip any content, I just need the taborder to be different in mobile screens vs desktop screens.